# ¿ cómo extraer únicamente el mes de una columna tipo datetime en un pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, date, busqueda, type

Dispongo de un datframe que contiene una fecha y deseo extrar el mes de la misma. Estos son los tipos de datos que manejo:

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000 entries, 0 to 1000
Data columns (total 30 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------          --------------  ----- 
 0   FECHA           1000 non-null   object
```

¿Cómo leo solo el mes?, ¿Busco parámetros como todas las fechas que sean 2020?, ¿todos los meses de febrero sean del año que sean?  etc

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas leer solo el mes convierte la fecha en un detatime y utiliza:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA']).dt.to_period('M')
```